# Conditional routing using React Navigation (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Building a React Native app, and I would to send a user to the next screen DEPENDING on the initial Select screen's state. So, if there there is 1 item selected, it should take the user to the Single screen. If more than 1, the Multiple screen.

As you can see, I made custom headerLeft and headerRight components. I would prefer to keep the routing this way, but somehow add the initial state into this context. Is there a way?

If I could somehow decouple the navigation options from the routes.js file and put them into the Screen components themselves, that would be awesome. But from what I researched, it doesn't seem like that the navigationOptions can directly access state.

Here's the relevant code (routes.js):

```
export default StackNavigator(
  {
    Select: {
      screen: Select,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: <View />,
        headerRight: (
          <HeaderRight
            navigation={navigation}
            destination=""
            showIcon
          />
        )
      })
    },
    Single: {
      screen: Single,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: (
          <HeaderLeft navigation={navigation} destination="back" showIcon />
        ),
        headerRight: (
          <HeaderRight navigation={navigation} destination="SingleSecond" />
        )
      })
    },
    Multiple: {
      screen: Multiple,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: <HeaderLeft navigation={navigation} destination="back" />,
        headerRight: (
          <HeaderRight navigation={navigation} destination="MultipleSecond" />
        )
      })
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: "float",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `${navigation.state.routeName}`,
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#000" },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff",
        textAlign: "center",
        alignSelf: "center"
      }
    })
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set params from a component these params can be accessed from navigation options.

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({ selectionState: "single" });
this.props.navigation.setParams({ selectionState: "multiple" });
```

and you can access the params from the navigation options like

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  let selected = navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.selectionState;
  return {
    headerRight: ...
  };
}
```

I hope this fills your needs, you need to set params after selecting something in your component. There is another way to dynamically set the initial state.

```
function getNavigation (selected = "single") {
  return StackNavigator({
    ...,
    { initialState = selected === "single" ? "Single" : "Multiple" }
  })
}
```

and then call this method with the selected argument to reset the screen.